# Are there testable predictions made by the Copenhagen interpretation that are incompatible with Pilot Wave or vice versa?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, bohmian-mechanics

As of right now, whenever right now happens to be, has anyone identified any promising experiments capable of distinguishing between the Copenhagen interpretation and the Pilot Wave interpretation of Quantum Mechanics?  If so, has any progress been made on performing these experiments?

Comment: I am not a physicist.  If my language is not sufficiently technical, I would love to improve it.  Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are different interpretations of quantum mechanics empirically distinguishable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133906/)

Comment: Answer to  a similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460388/

Comment: The earlier question/answers leave out analysis well related to this question. The Pilot Wave class with dBB and Bohmian Mechanics is often labeled theory as opposed to interpretation. Some papers claim that existing experiments rule this class out. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.2014.pdf *"...David Bohm’s assumption of an
“infinite-speed time-ordered quantum potential” is generally supposed to reproduce the experimental predictions of quantum mechanics... [but] the Michelson-Morley entanglement experiment (Figures 1 and 2) rules out Bohm’s “infinite-speed
time-ordered quantum potential”*.

Comment: I might normally add yet another answer (to the 6 existing) at that other question from 2014. But there has been a lot of research since then, specifically on the Bohmian theory side. The short comment I made above includes a paper written subsequently, and I could not really do justice to it in a comment. It would be nice to be able to present a properly analyzed answer here to the specific question asked: has there been any progress? Short answer: yes.